# docker connecting to host tunnel from container

Tags: docker, ssh-tunnel, docker-network, docker-container

I would like to connect from inside my docker container with a postgres db that is using a tunnel in the host. In the host I have a tunnel pointing to the DB host:

```
host$ sudo netstat -tulpen  | grep 555
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       535901      18361/ssh       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5555                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       535900      18361/ssh
```

the tunnel is setup with :

```
host$ ps -aux | grep 18361
ubuntu    9619  0.0  0.0  10432   628 pts/0    S+   10:11   0:00 grep --color=auto 18361
ubuntu   18361  0.0  0.0  46652  1420 ?        Ss   Nov16   0:00 ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -f -N -L 5555:localhost:5432 user@remotehost
```

and from the host I can launch psql commands:

```
host$ psql -h localhost -p 5555 --username user db_name
psql (9.3.15, server 9.5.4)
SSL connection (cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.
db_name=#
```

As I am using the network mode **BRIDGE** [I cannot use **HOST** as docker is not correctly exposing the containers ports to host see: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3442 ] I read that I  have to use the container ip:

```
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:6c:01:5c:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:6cff:fe01:5ca5/64 scope link
```

Which in this case would be **172.17.0.1**

However when I go inside the container:

```
host$ docker exec -ti container_name  /bin/bash
```

I try to connect I have:

```
container# psql -h 172.17.0.1 -p 5555                                                                                                                                                                                              
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5555?
```

Anything that I am missing ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You missed bind_address, so now your binding address is 127.0.0.1.
Setting your tunnel you have to add bind_address parameter.

> -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport

E.g.

```
sudo ssh -f -N -L 172.17.0.1:5555:localhost:5432 user@remotehost
```

Comment: When I attempt to bind my container ip (172.18.0.1) I get the following error


```bind [172.18.0.1]:4000: Can't assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 4000
Could not request local forwarding.```

Comment: It seems another process is listening on that port. If no process is listening, look at ssh config file about any LocalForward or AllowTcpForwarding directive

Comment: Thanks.  I should mention that this is on macos.  I got it to work just fine in Ubuntu.  The forwarding works on macos if I don't specify the 172.18.0.1.  When I get back in front of the mac, I'll look to adjust the ssh config with the forward option and report back.

Comment: From reading up on AllowTcpForwarding, this would need to be enabled on the server I'm connecting to.  This is enabled, because I am able to get the port forwarding to work just fine if I don't specify the address to bind to.