# Connect to ssh tunnel in host from podman container

Tags: ssh-tunnel, podman

I would like the container to access the remote server with a ssh tunnel on host.

It should be similar to this question. But I am using podman (MacOS) and I don't see any podman network interface in `ifconfig`. I see other people having `cni-podman0` but it looks like `cni` is deprecated in podman version 4.

[docker connecting to host tunnel from container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782404/docker-connecting-to-host-tunnel-from-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can use `host.containers.internal` from the container to access the remote server through the ssh tunnel on the host machine.